# debugging c++ in codelite

Tags: c++, debugging, ide, codelite

i am setting a break point beside the int x , and setting the ide to the debug mode,but nothing appear in the debugging window when i start debugging ???

**should i do something more ?**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;


    int x;
    cout<<"X = "<<x<<endl<<"enter new x \n X = ";
    cin>>x;

    cout<<endl<<"New X = "<<x<<endl;


}
```

Comment: It often works better to set a breakpoint on a line where something is actually going to execute (e.g., one of your `cout` lines).

Comment: nothing shows up,i set many breakpoints but i am missing something i don't know:(

Comment: Setting a breakpoint means code execution has stopped at that line. You need to step through the lines of code, using some click or command ( I don't know about codelite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several reasons for codelite not stopping:

1) Did you build your project with debugging information enabled? Make sure you select the 'Debug' configuration, this makes sure that -g is passed to gcc / g++

2) Try enabling the debugger log from: settings -> debugger settings -> GNU gdb debugger -> Misc -> enable debugger full log
this will produce more information on the interaction between between codelite and gdb - it will also tell you why gdb failed to stop, the log is printed into the 'Debugger' pane, under the 'Output' tab

Remember: codelite is just an interface to gdb, so if codelite did not break, it means that gdb did not instruct it to break...

Eran

Answer (score 1):

It is your ide forbids you to read uninitiated value 'int x'.
I debugged it under vs2008, and the break point will automatically be removed to cout line.
and continue debugging will get this :

[image]

Press 'continue' will get output in cmd window.

[image]

I hope this bring some help to you.